# Possible to install Windows 7 32-bit on an HP ML350 G6 server

Tags: windows-7

We have an application that does not support running on a 64-bit OS and also has no need for additional features present in Windows Server. We already have the ML350 G6 hardware but do not see Windows 7 drivers.

Since the latest Windows Server OS is 64-bit only we would be forced to run it on Windows Server 2008 a/k/a "Vista server" which we'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I contacted HP support and they assured me Windows 7 is unsupported on this hardware. Their recommended workaround is to install ESXi and run Win7 as a guest. Our application also does not support running in a virtual environment

Comment: We have been directed to not install Windows 7 due to lack of official support. I'm leaving question open for anyone who can confirm a working install using 2008 drivers on this hardware since it could be helpful for the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try, some/most of the windows 2008 drivers will work on windows 7.

Comment: +1 Have used Win2008 drivers in a similar situation. Worked fine but it was different Dell server hardware.  Dell also indicated unsuppoted but we got it working

Answer (score 2):

One option you can do is load Hyper-V Server 2008 R2, its free. Then load your 32bit Windows 7 as a Virtual Machine. As long as you don't have any specific hardware your app needs to work with this should run great and give you some additional flexibility for your server.

Answer (score 1):

Just try the installation. The only thing that's unique to the hardware is the RAID controller. Perhaps the ILO hardware. Check the Windows 2008 drivers if you need... Otherwise virtualized with ESXi and install W7 on top.